# Why does Alpakka not use the message pattern?

Tags: alpakka

If Alpakka is intended to be an alternative to Apache Camel then why does it not send some form of standardised Message object with a payload, headers, properties, MIME type etc. like all other integration projects do? (e.g. Mule, Spring Integration). It seems that just a bare payload is moved between the various flow steps.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of question you are going for here, it uses akka-streams API which is a streaming API built on top of akka, if you want an envelope just create an envelope and pass it, not sure why you expect that behavior, it has nothing to do with what akka-streams is offering

Comment: If a sample flow just adds numbers together and I pass in an envelope the flow will try to add the envelopes. I would want it to extract the payload, perform the operation, and the put the result into a new message envelope. This is what Camel does and it's incredibly useful.